# C++ with SDL Making a Grid for a CAD type application

Tags: c++, grid, sdl

I have started working on a CAD type program and I am not quite sure how to define a grid to the scale of a CAD program which is massive. The grid would have to contain coordinate points up to 7 decimal places or more and for like 10,000 units on the x and y axes. Storing every point would be too much for a computer to handle. What methods are out there to define such massive coordinate grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- Subdivide the coordinates into big and small units. For example, you can have a variable that stores things in "meters" and another in "millimeters". This depends on what your CAD program is for. As an example, have a look at how the [timeval structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) solves the problem, but for time.
- Use a big integer library, so you can use a single variable to express all points.